# Karate Gatling via karate takes 1 hr for duration 3 minutes. Tried akka config approach as well but no resolution

Tags: karate

Karate Gatling via karate takes 1 hr for a duration of 3 minutes. I tried akka config approach as well but no resolution. Please let me know what I should try to optimize this run in karate

akka {
actor { default-dispatcher { type = Dispatcher executor = "thread-pool-executor" thread-pool-executor { fixed-pool-size = 1000 } throughput = 1 } } }

karate and karate-gatling version is 1.3.1.

Comment: Requirement is hit 245 req/second

Comment: okay, you will have to help us here. I'm giving you a link as an example of how the community has helped us improve things. just saying things are slow is not going to get us anywhere: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/845

Comment: I will try but it is an office project that I can not share. I can assure you that I have not used any pause condition as mentioned in the link. For low req/second, it works well. However, for a single API and a shorter duration, it works fine. However, when I increase APIs in the setup to a high number i.e. 35 and run for 7req/sec for 3 minutes, it takes  1 hr to complete.

Comment: can you try karate 1.4.0.RC3 and see if that makes a difference. otherwise, you have to provide a way to replicate. if you have time, try 1.2.0 also and report any changes

Comment: okay, I will check my requirements with these karate and karate-gatling versions. If it does not help, I will try to share a maven project with the different version configuration in pom.xml which I am using. Thanks

Comment: Just an update Peter. One of the main culprits of this long test run was the machine on which this load test was run. I ran my load tests on a machine with high memory, and the test run time came down from 50 minutes to 15 minutes.

Would like to know if any other tweak will work to further reduce the total run time.

Comment: I think you are on the right track, nothing else to add